# The difference between "quelque chose tient à cœur à quelqu'un" and "quelqu'un tient à (faire) quelque chose"

Tags: sens, expressions

Are these two phrases nuanced in meaning in any way:

> une affaire qui me tient à cœur

and

> une affaire à laquelle je tiens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Qui me tient à cœur* : à laquelle **je suis attaché** (personnellement, affectivement)

*À laquelle je tiens* : c'est **important** pour moi (pour n'importe quelle raison, professionnelle, personnelle, ou pour d'autres raisons : économiques, ...)

On peut considérer que *tenir à coeur* implique qu'on *y tient*,
mais la réciproque n'est pas vraie.

Answer (score 1):

One is more of a superlative form of the other.

Compare:

> I hold this dear.

and

> I hold this dear to my heart.

The fact that the grammatical construction changes a bit in French isn't really important. One statement simply has more emphasis, nothing else.